# A simple question on the Lipschitz property

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $L$-Lipschitz, namely

$$|f(x) - f(y)|\leq L ||x-y||_2 \ \ \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n~.$$

How does this imply

$$||\nabla f||_2\leq L\ ?$$

It's clear when $n=1,$ but how can it be shown for higher $n?$

Comment: You can still use the mean value theorem.

Comment: Look at $f(x + t\nabla f(x)) - f(x)$ for small $\lvert t\rvert$.

Comment: What makes you think it's a silly question?

Comment: @Hedonist there's no such thing.

Comment: Only meant to say I should have thought a bit more before posting.